# Updating property binding

Tags: qt, qml

This code breaks the binding once the image is clicked. view.visible logic (conditions) will not work after that. It will continue to remain true. How can I change the view visibility? I think it makes sense to add conditions to visible property `visible: (model.count > 0) ? true : false` but I'm not sure how to write the ternary operator to achieve this.

```
  Text {
        id: text1
        visible: !view.visible
        text: qsTr("No tests results")
    }

   Image {
        id: img
        visible: !view.visible
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                view.visible = true
                console.log("Clicked")
            }
        }
    }

    ListView {
            id: view
            anchors.fill: parent
            visible: (model !== null) && (model.count > 0) ? true : false
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add another property and bind that in your conditional. For example:

```
    Text {
        id: text1
        visible: !view.visible
        text: qsTr("No tests results")
    }

    Image {
        id: img
        visible: !view.visible
        property bool showStuff: true
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                showStuff = false
                console.log("Clicked")
            }
        }
    }

    ListView {
            id: view
            anchors.fill: parent
            visible: (model.count > 0 && img.showStuff)
     }
```

The binding for view's visibility will be maintained.

Comment: I think I'm overthinking this way too much. But let me just clarify. When the (model !== null) && (model.count > 0) results to false, the listview visibility is false and it does not show. When that happens the text appears on the screen with the image. When I click the image I want the listview visibility to be changed backed to true

Comment: I think (model !== null) && (model.count > 0) || img.showStuff) is what would work. If the model equates to false, whenever I click the image it would equate to true and then it would be visible

Comment: However you shake out your conditional binding for view.visible is up to your needs, I'll leave that to you. What I was trying to highlight is a way to maintain that binding by simply flipping that property showStuff in the onClicked function. In your original code, the direct assignment to view.visible was breaking the binding you declared.

Comment: Here's more info from Qt on the subject: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html#creating-property-bindings-from-javascript -- specifically relevant, "A property with a binding is automatically updated as necessary. However, if the property is later assigned a static value from a JavaScript statement, the binding will be removed."